# android studio: cannot open this project, please retry with version 4.1 or newer

Tags: android

My android studio verison from Help > About

```
Android Studio 3.3.1
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5264788, built on January 29, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.0.5-arch1-1-ARCH
```

`build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
            credentials { username "48a9b4c06b5dabbc03328ddcdbb7dfd8fab253ae" }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and

`project/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
#Fri Apr 16 20:59:03 IST 2021
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

when i try `File > Sync Project with Gradle Files`

I keep getting

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 4.1 or newer.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 11s
ERROR: This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 4.1 or newer.
```

I am using  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'`  which is higher than `4.1`

What should i do get out of this error

**as per Answer:**

Updated it to

```
Android Studio 4.1.3
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.7199119, built on March 11, 2021
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.0.5-arch1-1-arch
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 2014M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: de.mprengemann.intellij.plugin.androidicons
Current Desktop: KDE
```

Comment: What version of android studio are you using?

Comment: added the android studio version in the edited question

Comment: You have a very old version of android studio which probably is not compatible you need to update it. Current stable release is 4.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your android studio and your project will Sync fine. Issues is not related to Gradle.

**In Android Studio go to** `Help->check for update`

then update your android studio